# How to simulate video input in the iOs simulator?

Tags: ios, video-processing

I'm writing an app that uses

```
- (void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;
```

to grab video frames and analyze them on the fly.  I'd like to be able to test this feature in the iOs simulator, but I can't figure out how to use a video file as an input to an AVCaptureSession.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you need a real device to test functions related to the camera. I'm not completely sure about it, but I use my iPod touch 4th gen for these kind of things.